# What is the difference between jquery .on and ._on

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between jquery `.on` and `._on`?

When I search the jquery API I only get `.on` returned. Google also does not return anything helpful. I'm definitely seeing it in code that works though, for example:

```
$grid._on("click",".gridSave:not(.disabled)", self.saveRow, self);
$grid.on("click",".gridSave.disabled", function(){ return false });
```

Comment: `._on()` doesn't exist in  `jQuery.fn` by default where chainable methods reside so might be  custom method. Where did you get that from? Is `$grid` even a jQuery object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_on` comes from [jqueryui widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget) [`_on`](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_on) while `.on` comes from [normal jquery handler functions](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

both are basically the same thing, they attach event handlers to an element. an example is when an element is clicked

> `_on( [suppressDisabledCheck ] [, element ], handlers )`
>   Binds event handlers to the specified element(s).
>   Delegation is supported via selectors inside the event names, e.g.,
>   "click .foo".